# I am getting Bad Type error in localhost PHPmyaddmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

How can I fix the following error:

[image: error bad type]

Comment: Update your phpMyAdmin and see if it helps. Please report bugs to phpMyAdmin

Comment: thx , i solved error , maybe it is time out error , New phpmyadmin Show loading